# Is bitcoin a better option than banks for transferring money from India to Hong Kong

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, currencies, wire-transfers

I live in HK and I need to transfer some amount from my Indian bank account to my wife's Hong Kong bank account. I tried bank wire transfer and I lost almost 11-12% of total amount. My friend also needs to send me some money from India because I'm helping him in his business. Assuming that my friend buys bitcoin from India and makes a transfer to my bitcoin wallet, and I convert that much bitcoins to HK dollar when there is not much rate fluctuation, is it a viable option to conduct money transfer internationally? Also, approximately how much percentage is lost in the transfer. I don't have a bitcoin wallet yet, but I and my friend are planning to start it because we may need to do more money transfer in future. Are there any legal complications in conducting money transfer like this? Please explain it to me like you would to a 12-year-old. Thank you very much.